# What is transaction "finality"?

Tags: transactions, locktime, sequence, checksequenceverify

bitcoind `IsFinalTx()` as seen [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/03858b23fe1d17e681eb18d24602b276020295a0/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L17-L28) checks the properties of a transaction in this order:

1. Is `nLockTime` exactly `0`? That's final. return.
2. If it's not `0`, is it below the current block height / time? If so, it's final. return.
3. Ensure that every tx input is exactly `0xffffffff`. If so, it's final.

Because these are checked in order with `return` statements, `nSequence` won't even be checked if `nLockTime == 0`. Furthermore, a transaction that is NOT past its `nLockTime` value could still be "final" as long as all the `nSequence` values are `0xffffffff`

[Non-final transactions are not valid in blocks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/could-i-mine-a-non-final-transaction), so my questions are:

- Why is a "bad" locktime ok as long as all sequences are final? The tx won't be mineable anyway, right?
- What are the implications for replace-by-fee and Check Sequence Verify transactions (when a non-final `nSequence` value is used)? Does this mean that to use those features, `nLockTime` has to be set a certain way?
- Or, maybe, because `nLockTime` has to be below the current time/height anyway, this is all just moot and really, `nSequence` doesn't really impact transaction finality at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is a "bad" locktime ok as long as all sequences are final? The tx won't be mineable anyway, right?

According to [BIP 68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0068.mediawiki), setting `nSequence` value to 0xFFFFFFFF for every input in the transaction disables `nLocktime`. So, whatever may be the value of `nLocktime`, it will have no effect on the transaction as far as `nSequence` value is 0xFFFFFFFF.

> What are the implications for replace-by-fee and Check Sequence Verify transactions (when a non-final nSequence value is used)? Does this mean that to use those features, nLockTime has to be set a certain way?

It considered a transaction has opted in to allow replacement of itself, if any of its inputs have an nSequence number LESS than 0xFFFFFFFE. To use `CSV` your `nSequence` value has to be <= 0xEFFFFFFF. If `nSequence` value > 0xEFFFFFFF, then there us no consensus meaning to the sequence number and it can be included in any block under all currently possible circumstances. So for using `nLocktime` along with Opt-in RBF, your `nSequence` value has to be between 0xF0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFD. Refer [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87372/what-does-the-sequence-in-a-transaction-input-mean/87376#87376) for more info on `nSequence` and how it has evolved in the last few years.

> Or, maybe, because nLockTime has to be below the current time/height anyway, this is all just moot and really, nSequence doesn't really impact transaction finality at all..

`nLocktime` is a transaction level feature while `nSequence` is an input level feature. So, the program basically is optimized so that individual inputs are not checked if the transaction itself is invalid due to `nLocktime`. If you check the function below `IsFinalTx`, it checks the validity of each transaction inputs by verifying that the `nSequence` numbers are valid.

Comment: So a value of `0xF0000000` has "no consensus meaning" -- but it is still signalling RBF right? So it still has mempool/policy meaning. This would be true for all transactions, version 1 or 2?

Comment: And, does this mean that ALL CSV txs are necessarily "replace-by-fee" as well?

Comment: @pinhead as I said in the answer there is no consensus meaning to the sequence number but Other rules apply. Yes, it will be signalling RBF. This changed meaning to `nSequence` was done as a part of BIP 68 soft fork and work for version>=2.

Comment: @pinhead Yes, all CSV tx signal RBF due to the nature in which the `nSequence` value is set

Answer (score 0):

> Why is a "bad" locktime ok as long as all sequences are final? The tx won't be mineable anyway, right?

With a final `nSequence`, the transaction *will* be mineable no matter the `nLockTime`.

> What are the implications for replace-by-fee and Check Sequence Verify transactions (when a non-final nSequence value is used)? Does this mean that to use those features, nLockTime has to be set a certain way?

No, it's not required.
Regarding the implications, if the `nSequence` is:

- `= 0xffffffff`, then the transaction is final no matter the `nLockTime`.
- `< 0xfffffffe`, then the transaction signals for RBF.
- `< 0xefffffff`, then the transaction signals [BIP68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0068.mediawiki) relative locktime. [More here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/87372/what-does-the-sequence-in-a-transaction-input-mean/87376#87376).

> Or, maybe, because nLockTime has to be below the current time/height anyway, this is all just moot and really, nSequence doesn't really impact transaction finality at all.

It does. It impacts finality by deactivating the check for `nLockTime` if it is set to the maximum value, and since BIP68 (consensus soft fork) was activated on the network it may impact finality by specifying a relative lock time.